# Integrity constrait violation while using Laravel updateOrCreate() method

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a voting system on my current Laravel site and there is a problem that i simply don't understand while using Laravel `updateOrCreate()` method.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
$vote = Vote::updateOrCreate(
    ['thread_id' => $id, 'user_id' => Auth::id()],
    ['type' => $request->type]
);
```

Is there is a vote with that `thread_id` and `user_id` update its `type` field using `$request->type` value. If not, create a new record. Either way, i'm getting an `Integrity constrait violation: 1048` error that says: `'user_id' cannot be null`

Am I doing something wrong with this method?

This is my `Vote` model migration:

```
Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('type');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Are you sure you are authenticated at the time of doing the `updateOrCreate` call?

Comment: Yes I am, it is the only way to get to the voting view

Comment: @jcalonso Actually, ``Auth::id()`` returns null. That's weird cause im logged in. The view where my upvote/dowvote buttons are is protected with the auth middleware.

Comment: What does `Auth::user()` return?

Comment: It returns nulls just like ``Auth::id()`` does.

Comment: I forgot something importat that might be causing this problem. The upvote/downvote system is made within a Vue component inside ``resources/js/components``. I am using axios to post my vote ``type`` but... The ``Auth::user()`` should work inside my controller, doesn't it ?

Comment: I guess it depends where your route sits. Is this an API route?

Comment: Yes @Namoshek, axios is working with an API route.

Comment: Well, that was it. I have to use a ``web.php`` route, not a ``api.php`` route. Thanks a lot to both of you!